# Making an array from two another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects (10 objects in each arrray) ->

```
arr1 = [{name: '', age: ''}...]
```

and

```
arr2 = [{surname: '', position: ''}...]
```

which I hold in two separated states.
My goal is to create the third array of the objects which contains also 10 elements

```
arr3=[{name: arr1.name, surname: arr2.surname}...]
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/javascript/how-to-merge-two-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: Please format your question so it is easier to read.

Comment: So the indexes line up? So 1 is 1 and 2 is 2?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is a 1 to 1 where each index matches, it is a simple Array map and using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy over the properties and values.

```js
const arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}];
const arr2 = [{c: 11, d: 22}, {c: 33, d: 44}];

const arr3 = arr1.map((obj, ind) => ({...obj, ...arr2[ind]}), []);

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could combine both arrays using a for loop:

```js
const arr3 = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  arr3[i] = {
    name: arr1[i].name,
    surname: arr2[i].surname
  }
}
```

Comment: Somebody must have downvoted you because of the lack of explanation. If you take a look at the other answers, they include a bit of explanation/preamble as well as the code. I've edited your question a little bit to show you how a few minor improvements can turn it around.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need,

```
let arr3 = []    
arr1.forEach((obj1, index) => {
 let obj3 = {...obj1, ...arr2[index]}
 arr3.push(obj3)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the indexes are assumed to match between the two arrays** (which also implies that the two arrays are the same length), you can [use `map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on one array and use its index parameter to reference the other array.  (It doesn't really matter which.)

For example:

```
const arr3 = arr1.map((a, i) => ({
  name: a.name,
  surname: arr2[i].surname
}));
```

Note that this is based on the example shown, where only two properties (one from each array) are in the resulting objects.  If you want *all* properties in the resulting objects, you don't need to specify all of them.  You can just combine them all:

```
const arr3 = arr1.map((a, i) => ({
  ...a,
  ...arr2[i]
}));
```

Comment: same answer as mine, hope you don't get a downvote too!

Answer (score -2):

I don't get exactly what do you want to do but I think this question has been answered a few times.

You wanna do arr1 + arr2 ? Like they follow each others in the array3 ?

Comment: how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).